# Codeigniter pagination list all records from database table instead of list limit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used below code for codeigniter pagination.But it list all reocrds from the database table .Pagination not working

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM list AS a ".$search_condition."  "; 
$query = $this->db->query($SQL); 
$finaldata=array();
$finaldata['num_results']= $query->num_rows();      
//how many blogs will be shown in a page
$limit = $finaldata['num_results'];
$start_limit = ($offset-1) * $limit;

echo $SQL = "SELECT * FROM list AS a   ".$search_condition." LIMIT ".$start_limit.",".$limit." "; 
$query = $this->db->query($SQL); 

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{   
$finaldata['data']= $query->result_array();              
} 

// load pagination library
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config = array();
$config['base_url'] = site_url("adminuser/list");
$config['total_rows'] = $finaldata['num_results'];
$config['per_page'] = $limit;
//which uri segment indicates pagination number
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
//max links on a page will be shown
$config['num_links'] = 5;
//various pagination configuration
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
<! some code here ->
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$finaldata['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('admin/list',$finaldata);
```

I try to list 10 records per page in the list page . but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

First of you're declaring useless variables. Your first SQL should contain `COUNT(*)`.

You really do not need `$limit` you are using it only once, one row bellow declaration also your indentation is making it almost unreadable and try not to connect strings using dots, use curly brackets.

```php
"SELECT * FROM list AS a {$search_condition} LIMIT {$start_limit}, {$limit}";
```

Now you can read it properly and I think it should solve your problem.
Try to optimize your code and not having mess.
Finally, in your configuration you have `per_page` limit the same as `total_rows`. You defined `$limit = $finaldata['num_results']`, change this value:

```php
$config['per_page'] = $limit;
```